# akka 2.0 send message to self

Tags: scala, akka

using Akka 2.0 trying to send a message to self (using the ask pattern)

```
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor, ActorSystem}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util.Timeout
object askTest extends App{
   implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
   val system = ActorSystem("AskTestSystem")
   val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor), name = "myActor")
   val future: Future[Foo] = ask(myActor, Foo("test")).mapTo[Foo]
   val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
   println(result)
}
case class Foo(name:String){
  override def toString = "Foo "+name
}

  class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Foo(a) => self ! Foo("buzz "+a)
    case any => println(any+" that was unexpected")
  }
 }
```

however it crashes with Timeout exception with the following trace :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:100)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at akkaTest.askTest$delayedInit$body.apply(askTest.scala:33)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at akkaTest.askTest$.main(askTest.scala:13)
    at akkaTest.askTest.main(askTest.scala)
```

Comment: why do you need `system.shutdown()`? Isn't it supposed to shutdown all actors (in this case before anything else has been done)?

Comment: @Ashalynd thanks, it was a mistake , I removed it now . but still cannot send to self

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code does what you told it to do: the actor indefinitely sends a message to itself. Because it sends the message to no one except self, your `ask` pattern just can't work, because `ask` is waiting for a message to be sent to the *sender*, not *self*.

`self` is a reference to the current actor, you use it when you want the actor to send message to itself. `sender` is a reference to an actor which has sent the message which is currently being processed. You use it if you want to "answer" to the sender.

`ask` pattern creates an implicit actor which becomes `sender` reference in the target actor - this is very natural. So you need to change `self ! Foo("buzz " + a)` to `sender ! Foo("buzz " + a)`, and your code will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the message send to self in my real application I am actually using a Partial receive and I need it also for calling it's own methods asynchronously. so I do need to send it to self

Comment: @igx, you do understand that your code won't work, don't you? It does not demonstrate what you intend to do. `ask` pattern is external to the actor, so it just cannot handle messages sent to `self`.

Comment: @igx, in fact, your code is somewhat equivalent to infinite recursion: `def foo(a: String) { this.foo("buzz " + a) }`. There is *no* way to handle it outside of the function. Same thing goes for actors.

Comment: yes, I do understand that my code doen't work , so you are actually saying that messages cannot be send to self correct ?

Comment: @igx, they *can* be sent to self, but they should be handled in the actor. I see that this is perfectly described by Alexey in another answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can send messages to `self`, but you can't wait for a reply. Because you won't get the new message until you finish handling the current message, and if you use `ask`, you won't finish handling the current message until you get a reply to the new message! So you are creating a deadlock.

But in the case of code in question, you are *not* asking `self` for a reply at all. The actor created by `ask` is waiting for the reply from `myActor`, and isn't getting it (because the code of `TestActor` doesn't send any *reply*, and sends a message to `self` instead).

You can see that `self ! message` works by changing `TestActor` a bit:

```
case class Bar(name: String)

class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Foo(a) => self ! Bar(a)
    case Bar(a) => println("Got a message to self: " + a)
    case any => println(any+" that was unexpected")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey , this is exactly what I need, can you please add sample code ?

Comment: Code for sending messages to `self`? It's just `self ! message`, as you have.

Comment: This is why I was trying to demonstrate. it seems infinite loop

Comment: Yes, because that's what your code says: when `TestActor` receives a `Foo`, it sends another `Foo` to itself, then handles it by sending another `Foo` to itself, etc. See the edited answer.

Comment: actually, my apology , I got stuck in misconception and banging my head in the wall .... all clear now

Answer (score 0):

My apology, I know this is really an old question but it recently surfaced in my use cases. Just wanted to share my 2 cents.

I wanted to handle a message by routing it to self with updated parameters. And I'm expecting results by using ask pattern. To get this working, I had to use a second proxy actor, which main purpose is to relay to message back to the main actor.

```
       (augmented)
Main Actor --> Proxy Actor --> Main Actor
           ask             ask
```

This has allowed me to ask for the results, at the costs of some extra overheads.